# FOS UserBundle UserManager::__construct() must be an instance of ObjectManager

Tags: symfony, symfony4, fosuserbundle

Fresh installation of symfony 4.4, then symfony flex and some common recipes, then I was trying to setup fos userbundle, I have this issue I cannot get around.

```
Argument 3 passed to FOS\UserBundle\Doctrine\UserManager::__construct() must be an instance of Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager, instance of Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager given, called in /srv/www/alexseif/var/cache/dev/ContainerYzHcxci/srcApp_KernelDevDebugContainer.php on line 1660
```

Answer (score 6):

Aside from the FOSUserBundle being no longer maintained, and therefor shouldn't be used in new Projects, I had to solve this problem too:

Adding `"doctrine/common": "^2.8",` to the composer.json was enough in my case.

Comment: Thank you, I will try that.. MAN FOS is out, I guess we gotta work on old projects again xD

Comment: How "nice" is to end up using libs just before the end of their life... lot of fun.. 

Comment: Package doctrine/reflection is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use roave/better-reflection instead.